# Monitor upgrade candidates (hi res, hi refresh rate?)

Tags: monitors, 4k

Since my Vega64 just went up in smoke, I've recently bought a 6900XT GPU (damn you scalpers) and am thinking about upgrading my monitor to go with it. I've been using a Dell Ultrasharp 1440p for a while, but it's just a bog-standard office monitor so the tearing is unbelievable and I'm noticing it more and more now.

Since I have the horsepower, I'm thinking of going to 4k, but I am torn, since I don't seem to be able to find a monitor with just the right combo of the following ideal specs:

- High refresh rate (120Hz or above, not bothered about it being 144Hz specifically, nor any kind of overclocking)
- 4K ideally (or at least a leap up from 2160x1440, particularly if the screen will be physically larger).
- 1-2ms response times
- 27" to ~38" panel (28-32" being ideal I think).
- Not a super-ultrawide, but no less than 3440x1600 if it's a widescreen.

I am a bit constrained by space, so I think I've decided that a 32" 4K flat or curved panel would be ideal, but there just do not seem to be any 4K high-refresh rate 32" panels out there at the moment. Does anyone have recommendations for this - or know if any are on the horizon in 2021?

Since I'm struggling to find the above, I'm considering a ultrawidescreen at 1600 vertical such as the LG 38GL950G or 38GN950, however, these are expensive and possibly a bit large for my space. Alternatively, the 'safe' option is a direct swap for another 27" 4K flat panel such as the LG 27GN950, which seems to be *the* gaming monitor of choice at the moment (but no stock anywhere  ). The Samsung Odyssey line up is compelling too, but no 4K offerings at the moment.

So in effect, I'm trying to find a happy medium for the above. Any recommendations/personal anecdotes welcome.

Comment: I don't think 4K is very useful at 27". 1440p/144Hz at 32" is what I found my perfect middle ground to be, and can be quite affordable as well.

Comment: My reservation about 1440p on a bigger screen is that I have gotten used to 1440p @ 27", and so any larger screen is actually going to be a step down in pixel density and clarity. I would like to gain a bit of screen real estate with a 28-32", but I don't want *less* clarity than I already enjoy for it (and the Dell Ultrasharps earn their name well) - hence 4K @ 32" being my ideal sweetspot I think (but since there seemingly aren't any, I'm prepared to go down to 27/28")

Comment: Apparently the ASUS PG32UQX is due to release soon, though it is rather expensive.

Comment: And the Acer XB323QK NV in May for a more reasonable 1200$.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - the Acer looks promising at that price point. Shame it seems to only be HDR 400, but that's by no means a deal breaker